# How can i google something into my browser through python script?

Tags: python, web, google-search

How do i make my script google something in my default browser

Example:

```
a = input("What to google? ")
google(a)
#this should google the input in default browser
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I want to search for a specific thing in google not open a url

Comment: That's just opening a specific URL on google.com, isn't it?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

For searching in google, let's say we want to search 'python program for windows'.

The url will be `https://www.google.com/search?q=python+program+for+windows`. This shows that the space should be replaced with `+`

Here's the code:

```py
import os
def google(a):
    d = "https://google.com/search?q="
    a = a.replace(' ','+')
    os.system("start " + d + a)

a = input("what to google? ")
google(a)
print(a + " googled...")
```

Comment: `start` only really works on Windows.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted! thanx and it also opens in default browser

Comment: @JoachimSauer I am in windows so it worked for me

Comment: @BartholoMew: you didn't specify that you're on Windows and Questions/Answers should be useful for other users in the future too. IMO the answer by RMRiver is much more useful *and* shorter.

Answer (score 2):

If it's something fairly simple to google:

```
import webbrowser
a = input("What to google? ")

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/search?q={}'.format('+'.join(a.split())))
```

OR

```
import webbrowser
a = input("What to google? ")

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/search?q={}'.format(a.replace(' ', '+')))
```